# Edges do not match colspan table itext

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I have done
business with iText, I
created a table with 9
columns, I have grouped the
first 4 to 1, then I have the
next 4 grouped in one,
staying one at the end, the
point is assigned
cell.setBorderwidth = 2 in
all cells, to generate the
document do not match
edges. 
Hope you can help
me.

[image]

[image]

Here is code used:

```
public PdfPTable createTable5() throws DocumentException {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
    table.setTotalWidth(540);
    //table.setWidthPercentage(105);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.setLockedWidth(true);

    table.setWidths(new float[]{26.16f,48.77f,48.77f,48.77f,40.06f,56.64f,78.41f,53.1f,59.2f,80.11f});
    PdfPCell cell;

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ",subFont));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setBorderWidth(0);
    //cell.setBorderWidthRight(0);
    //cell.setColspan(4);
    table.addCell(cell);


    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cantidades por material",subFont));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.setUseAscender(true);
    cell.setBorderWidth(2);
    cell.setBorderWidthRight(0);
    cell.setColspan(4);
    cell.setFixedHeight(g);

    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Costo por material",subFont));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.setUseAscender(true);
    cell.setBorderWidth(2);
    cell.setBorderWidthRight(0);
    cell.setColspan(4);
    cell.setFixedHeight(g);
    table.addCell(cell);

    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total",subFont));// Error in Border
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.setUseAscender(true);
    cell.setBorderWidth(2);
    //cell.setColspan(1);
    cell.setFixedHeight(g);
    //cell.setBorderWidthRight(0);
    table.addCell(cell);

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Still no solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `setUseBorderPadding(true)` for each cell.